# Redirecting to Same Form for Search Results makes Error

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, search, web-applications, routes

I am trying to simply redirect the result to the same action of the controller using the "form tag"

```
<%= form_tag(request.original_url, method: ":GET") do %>
```

This is my current rake routes:

```
                            Prefix Verb     URI Pattern                                   Controller#Action
                   human_resources GET      /human_resources(.:format)                    human_resources#index
          human_resources_settings GET      /human_resources/settings(.:format)           human_resources/settings#index
human_resources_settings_constants GET      /human_resources/settings/constants(.:format) human_resources/settings/constants#index
                        test_index GET      /test(.:format)                               test#index
                              root GET      /                                             home#index
```

I am getting

```
No route matches [POST] "/human_resources/settings/constants"
```

I am simply trying to redirect to back settings/constants. the route clearly matches `"/human_resources/settings/constants(.:format)"`; The purpose of the redirect is beca has search results. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> No route matches [POST] "/human_resources/settings/constants"

`method: ":GET"` is wrong. The below code should work

```
<%= form_tag(request.original_url, method: :get) do %>
```